# How to get the real screen size(screen resolution) by using js

Tags: javascript, screen, screen-resolution, screen-size, retina

### I just wonder whether there exists a way to get screen real size(screen resolution) in js.

1. I know the `screen` API, but its result not what I wanted.

```js
screen;
// Screen {availWidth: 1680, availHeight: 973, width: 1680, height: 1050, colorDepth: 30, …}

screen.width;
// 1680

screen.height;
// 1050
```

which, I got `width: 1680, height: 1050`;

actually, the screen size is `2880 x 1800`;

> my screenshots

[image]

[image]

### So, anyone can help?

---

### update for Apple `Retina Screen` Bug Reason ⚠️

> Apple Retina Screen `default` auto scale to `1680px x 1050px`

As you can't get the real retina screen size scale ratio, so the result will not be `2880px x 1800px`;

But the below solution is also right, as it read screen size is `1680px x 1050px`, thefore result is `3360px x 2100px`;

```js
(function getResolution() {
  const realWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
  const realHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
  console.log(`
    Your screen resolution is: ${realWidth} x ${realHeight}
    Your screen devicePixelRatio is: ${window.devicePixelRatio}
    Your screen width is: ${window.screen.width}
    Your screen height is: ${window.screen.height}
  `);
})();
// Your screen resolution is: 3840 x 2160 (4K)
// Your screen resolution is:  3360 x 2100 ( 3K? Retina Screen)
// Your screen resolution is: 1920 x 1080 ( 1080P / FHD)
```

[image]

> refs

https://www.cnblogs.com/xgqfrms/p/14196834.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

Comment: What are the display preferences ? Do you have retina scaling on ?

Comment: @Richard yeah, MBP 2018 retina, but using the default for display.

Comment: solution: `screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio` & `screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio`, get the real `screen resolution`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen Resolution ≠ Window width 
most os changing screen dpi so screen.width mostly return screen size with os dpi for for example my screen resolution is 1920x1080 and windows defult dpi is 125 so js screen.width return 1600px

use this:

```js
function getResolution() {
  const realWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
  const realHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
  console.log(`Your screen resolution is: ${realWidth} x ${realHeight}`);
}

// test
getResolution();
// Your screen resolution is: 3840 x 2160
```

[image]

Comment: it's not copy & paste. you can also change document zoom. use this style: html {zoom: 0.75}

Comment: This method produces 2208x1242 for iPhone8 plus in the emaultion mode both in Chrome and FF. Though specs say it's actually 1920x1080. The results seem to be correct for iPhone 8, iPhone X though.

Comment: Still can not infer why the MacOS retina display number is different from `screen.width * devicePixelRatio`. Screen Resolution ≠ Window width , but why? Better if there is any source.

Comment: @silencej please see the question `update for Apple Retina Screen Bug Reason ⚠️` section, it maybe helps you get the reason why.