# How To Detect HARDWARE Display Resolution?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to detect the HARDWARE (not viewport, not browser window, etc.) display resolution using either JavaScript or CSS?  I'm assuming that CSS doesn't work, but I could be wrong about that.  I'm very familiar with the various JavaScript techniques used to determine browser window and viewport resolution.  **What I haven't found anywhere is a method to detect a device's native HARDWARE display resolution.**

Let me define "native HARDWARE resolution" with an example.  A MacBook Pro (2019) has a viewport resolution of 1536 x 960 **when its operating system display scaling** is set to smallest text size, which is the maximum viewport resolution.  Its native HARDWARE resolution is 3072 x 1920, which is 2.0 times the resolution of the maximum viewport resolution.

I want to detect the HARDWARE resolution of 3072 x 1920 on the MacBook Pro.  [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462643/how-to-get-the-real-screen-sizescreen-resolution-by-using-js) attempts to explain how to arrive at HARDWARE resolution but it doesn't work for all devices.  That's because Windows 10 scales `windows.devicePixelRatio` when the browser is zoomed **or** when Windows 10 display scaling is set to something other than 100%.  Apple devices don't change `windows.devicePixelRatio` when the browser is zoomed or operating system display scaling is changed, so the calculation shown in the post will return an incorrect value for Apple devices.

A CSS solution would be preferred, but I think that's impossible.  If there's no CSS solution, is there a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that isn't available. It would have pretty bad privacy implications (fingerprinting).

As far as i know, even the size of the *window* (which you currently generally do have available in javascript), is being transitioned out or slightly offset/randomized for privacy sake. Mostly just in privacy addons and privacy-oriented builds (for now), but that is often how those changes take root.

Edit: You may find [deviceinfo.me](https://www.deviceinfo.me/) interesting, it shows what kind of information they can piece together about you; so effectively what sort of data is up for grabs.